# InfluxDB: How to increase the memory to avoid write timeout?

Tags: influxdb

I have recently deployed the influxDB using the docker image. However, I am hitting write timeout whenever the memory hits 1Gib.

Below are my configs for the docker container

```
    "Config": {
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "Cmd": [
            "influxd"
        ],
        "Domainname": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "/entrypoint.sh"
        ],
        "Env": [
            "INFLUXD_STORAGE_CACHE_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE=4294967296",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "GOSU_VER=1.12",
            "INFLUXDB_VERSION=2.1.1",
            "INFLUX_CLI_VERSION=2.2.1",
            "INFLUX_CONFIGS_PATH=/etc/influxdb2/influx-configs",
            "INFLUXD_INIT_PORT=9999",
            "INFLUXD_INIT_PING_ATTEMPTS=600",
            "DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_CLI_CONFIG_NAME=default"
        ],
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8086/tcp": {}
        },
        "Hostname": "9e338154d88e",
        "Image": "influxdb:latest",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.swarm.node.id": "vcm3hdheg7m1r6vnod6xdgyum",
            "com.docker.swarm.service.id": "s5385gxt9pnbb55y595yyj6ur",
            "com.docker.swarm.service.name": "influx",
            "com.docker.swarm.task": "",
            "com.docker.swarm.task.id": "zodo5rzedn0q7w00nfidx1z43",
            "com.docker.swarm.task.name": "influx.2.zodo5rzedn0q7w00nfidx1z43"
        },
        "OnBuild": null,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Tty": false,
        "User": "",
        "Volumes": {
            "/etc/influxdb2": {},
            "/var/lib/influxdb2": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": ""
    },
```

May I know what I can change to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well we faced the same issue. I can suggest you to do the followings:

1. Make sure that your client timeouts are increased enough (connect, read, write). InfluxDB's timeouts are limitless by default.
2. Make sure to use the latest InfluxDB version, it would have all the bugs fixed.
3. Paginate your data and save in chunks. Do not save all of the data at once. You know, in any kind of BE code, there should always be limits for each process at a time.